# Oracle forms master detail associated records are not displayed when performing query

Tags: oracle11g, block, master-detail, oracleforms

I have a master detail application in which I have a data block master and two detail, the problem arises when I run a query on the master block, then I jump the cursor immediately to a text item in the detail, and also shows me that no associated records.

Any idea why this might happen?

Attached images before and after executing the query:

[image: before]
[image: after]

Comment: Are you using the block 'Relations' to set up the master detail relation between the two blocks? If not you need to separately move to the details block and explicitly run Execute_Query.

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message you(or forms implicitly) are trying to move to a block without any navigable items. Please notice that in Forms you need to move to a block to query it and to be able to do this you need at least one navigable items. Meaning that you can't have only display items in a block nor you can't have all items in a block disabled,